# change the image name in php

Tags: php

hello i have the following code to change the image name of upload picture

```
$TARGET_PATH="pics/";
$TARGET_PATH =$TARGET_PATH . basename( $_FILES['photo']).'.jpg';
while (file_exists($TARGET_PATH))
    {
$TARGET_PATH =$TARGET_PATH . basename( $_FILES['photo']) . uniqid() . '.jpg';
}
```

This change the name of image or file but dont sho the extention it just show dot(.) at end of name i.e  1=>file.
2=>filefile9534803.

Comment: You will need to add more context to this. The `.jpg` extension is definitely added if the file exists, but the whole code doesn't seem to make sense yet - the result will be a mess

Comment: Why are you continuously appending `$TARGET_PATH` to itself?

Comment: now i edit my question target path is directory name actually i want to save the image come from a client(ipod) into a directory on the server and the path to database and if there is an image with the same name than it could change the name through uniqid().

Comment: if file exists, "while loop" is a never-ending loop, use "if" statement instead of "while loop"

Comment: this is not the problem ykartal actually i want to get the extention of image

Comment: yeah, You need to give more codes us to understand the problem. As your given code, Any problem is seen.

Comment: At which point and how do you print the output, i.e. "1=>file."?

Answer (score 1):

```
// $original = '/tmp/file.jpg';

$dir = 'foo' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$file = pathinfo($original);

do {
    $target = $dir . $file['filename'] . uniqid() . '.' . $file['extension'];
} while (file_exists($target));

echo $target; // foo/file4b3403665fea6.jpg
```